# Grails getting stuck on startup, on a fresh server

Tags: java, linux, grails, virtual-machine

I just got a fresh VM(Proxmox 1.9) instance of Ubuntu 12.04LTS. I did following:

1. Installed Sun Java 7 JDK and set up JAVA_HOME
2. Downloaded Grails 2.2.0 and set up GRAILS_HOME and PATH

Running

```
$ grails
```

Is always stuck on :

```
| Loading Grails 2.2.0
```

or sometimes it gets as far as

```
| Configuring classpath
```

I can only terminate the process using `kill -9 <pid>`  /:
I just got following exception too:

```
$ grails          
Exception in thread "Reference Handler" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.notifyAll(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.enqueue(ReferenceQueue.java:68)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:146)



$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          4096       1129       2966          0          0       1129
-/+ buffers/cache:          0       4096
Swap:            0          0          0


$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_11"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_11-b21)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.6-b04, mixed mode)
$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_11
```

I've tried looking for any system logs but no luck... just [this Java log trace](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=YEesBGXn)... very long one
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=YEesBGXn

Running with following JAVA_OPTS

```
$ echo $JAVA_OPTS
-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Dgrails.env=development -server -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

Shows a **very unusual garbage collection**, much more rapidly than on my local machine, **over 30 cycles in just on second !!!!**

```
$ grails
[GC [DefNew: 13336K->933K(19648K), 0.0034700 secs] 13336K->933K(63360K), 0.0035060 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
[GC [DefNew: 12566K->806K(19648K), 0.0029880 secs] 12566K->806K(63360K), 0.0030090 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
[GC [DefNew: 10728K->640K(19648K), 0.0020080 secs] 10728K->640K(63360K), 0.0020290 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
[GC [DefNew: 10717K->625K(19648K), 0.0021550 secs] 10717K->625K(63360K), 0.0021740 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
[GC [DefNew: 11185K->895K(19648K), 0.0028080 secs] 11185K->895K(63360K), 0.0028280 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
[GC [DefNew: 11239K->966K(19648K), 0.0027430 secs] 11239K->966K(63360K), 0.0027640 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
[GC [DefNew: 11190K->959K(19648K), 0.0028930 secs] 11190K->959K(63360K), 0.0029140 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
[GC [DefNew: 10801K->931K(19648K), 0.0027570 secs] 10801K->931K(63360K), 0.0027790 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
[GC [DefNew: 11730K->1483K(19648K), 0.0032850 secs] 11730K->1483K(63360K), 0.0033060 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
[GC [DefNew: 12693K->791K(19648K), 0.0036170 secs] 12693K->1286K(63360K), 0.0036380 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
[GC [DefNew: 10694K->623K(19648K), 0.0025120 secs] 11189K->1118K(63360K), 0.0025320 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
[GC [DefNew: 10457K->596K(19648K), 0.0016330 secs] 10952K->1091K(63360K), 0.0016540 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
[GC [DefNew: 10475K->604K(19648K), 0.0016960 secs] 10970K->1099K(63360K), 0.0017170 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
[GC [DefNew: 10500K->621K(19648K), 0.0017230 secs] 10995K->1116K(63360K), 0.0017600 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
[GC [DefNew: 11960K->848K(19648K), 0.0023630 secs] 12455K->1343K(63360K), 0.0023830 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
[GC [DefNew: 10656K->736K(19648K), 0.0020860 secs] 11151K->1231K(63360K), 0.0021090 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
[GC [DefNew: 10706K->785K(19648K), 0.0022890 secs] 11201K->1330K(63360K), 0.0023100 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
[GC [DefNew: 12704K->1209K(19648K), 0.0031890 secs] 13249K->1754K(63360K), 0.0032090 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
[GC [DefNew: 11009K->988K(19648K), 0.0030880 secs] 11555K->1737K(63360K), 0.0031090 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
[GC [DefNew: 10910K->1042K(19648K), 0.0026880 secs] 11659K->1791K(63360K), 0.0027080 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
[GC [DefNew: 11699K->1233K(19648K), 0.0029880 secs] 12447K->1990K(63360K), 0.0030080 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
[GC [DefNew: 11312K->1098K(19648K), 0.0032090 secs] 12069K->2088K(63360K), 0.0032280 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
[GC [DefNew: 11480K->1169K(19648K), 0.0028980 secs] 12470K->2199K(63360K), 0.0029190 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
[GC [DefNew: 11067K->996K(19648K), 0.0028780 secs] 12096K->2199K(63360K), 0.0028980 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
[GC [DefNew: 10838K->987K(19648K), 0.0023150 secs] 12040K->2189K(63360K), 0.0023360 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
[GC [DefNew: 10785K->989K(19648K), 0.0020500 secs] 11988K->2192K(63360K), 0.0020700 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
[GC [DefNew: 10842K->1010K(19648K), 0.0020970 secs] 12044K->2212K(63360K), 0.0021170 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
[GC [DefNew: 11668K->1184K(19648K), 0.0024270 secs] 12870K->2386K(63360K), 0.0024470 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
[GC [DefNew: 11840K->854K(19648K), 0.0030320 secs] 13043K->2572K(63360K), 0.0030540 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 

[GC [DefNew: 11890K->1345K(19648K), 0.0025590 secs] 13608K->3063K(63360K), 0.0025810 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
[GC [DefNew: 11306K->1007K(19648K), 0.0022660 secs] 13024K->3022K(63360K), 0.0022860 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
[GC [DefNew: 10991K->1059K(19648K), 0.0017130 secs] 13006K->3074K(63360K), 0.0017360 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
[GC [DefNew: 11440K->1255K(19648K), 0.0023460 secs] 13455K->3270K(63360K), 0.0023690 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
[GC [DefNew: 11989K->1298K(19648K), 0.0024010 secs] 14004K->3490K(63360K), 0.0024230 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
[GC [DefNew: 18770K->1948K(19648K), 0.0051470 secs] 20962K->4504K(63360K), 0.0051710 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
| Loading Grails 2.2.0
[GC [DefNew: 15322K->1119K(19648K), 0.0060270 secs] 18786K->5620K(63360K), 0.0060520 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
[GC [DefNew: 12134K->1357K(19648K), 0.0036970 secs] 16635K->5913K(63360K), 0.0037210 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
[GC [DefNew: 18695K->2148K(19648K), 0.0078430 secs] 23251K->7738K(63360K), 0.0078680 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
[GC [DefNew: 15902K->825K(19648K), 0.0071910 secs] 21492K->8544K(63360K), 0.0072170 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs] 
[GC [DefNew: 10669K->815K(19648K), 0.0028670 secs] 18388K->8535K(63360K), 0.0028910 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
[GC [DefNew: 12030K->1121K(19648K), 0.0037650 secs] 19750K->8840K(63360K), 0.0037880 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
| Downloading: ivy-1.0.xml
| Downloading: ivy-3.2.3.xml
```

Any ideas about what might be wrong here?

Thanks a bunch,

Amit.

Comment: The extra gc work might be caused by lack of memory, try increasing MaxPermSize and Xmx. If that doesn't work, set your log levels to debug in Config.groovy and check what's the app doing when it freezes.

Comment: Thanks Raphael! I did try already with a total of 2GB and nothing changes. Note that I was only running 'grails' not any application even, since Grails doesn't even get to the part of loading my classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

This is an issue of the Proxmox virtual machine described here: http://forum.proxmox.com/archive/index.php/t-6998.html

It helped to give the machine more CPU power.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the problem of Proxmox, it is the problem of OpenVZ. If you use Proxmox, I suggest you take a kvm instance. But it seems that OpenVZ is ok with IBM JDK, maybe you can try IBM's Java runtime. You'd better not run JVM in OpenVZ.